# Can I add EdgeHTML Edge webview (not Chromium Edge webview) to a WinForms or WPF window?

Tags: .net, microsoft-edge

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms) explains how to a embed Chromium Edge view to a WinForms window. Is it possible to do same thing but with EdgeHTML Edge?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to use Edge WebView in WinForms and WPF. Microsoft has docs about this:

1. [WebView control for Windows Forms and WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview)
2. [Bringing a modern WebView to your .NET WinForms and WPF Apps](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/)

But WebView will eventually be replaced by WebView2. Thus, the WebView has been deprecated within the Toolkit.